# Access 2007 filtering by text on a form using a foreign key

Tags: ms-access

I have created a tabular form in Microsoft Access 2007. On the form is a textbox, and I wish to filter the items in the form.

The problem is that one of the fields in the form is a foreign key which references a linked table holding Company names.

When I run the code below, and type a company name in the text box + hit return, I am only able to search for numeric values that correspond to the company name:

```
Private Sub Text22_AfterUpdate()
Dim mFilter As String
Dim mQuery1 As String

If IsNull(Me.Text22) Then
    mQuery1 = ""
Else
    mQuery1 = Me.Text22
End If

mFilter = "[ID] Like ""*" & mQuery1 & "*"""
mFilter = (mFilter + " OR ") & "[Supplier] Like ""*" & mQuery1 & "*"""

temp = MsgBox(mFilter, vbOKOnly)

Me.Filter = mFilter
Me.FilterOn = True
Me.Requery
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is to include the company name that you want to filter on in the query linked to the tabular form.
Something like:

```
SELECT Invoice.ID, 
       Invoice.Amount, 
       Invoice.SupplierID,
       Supplier.CompanyName
FROM   Invoice
  INNER JOIN Supplier ON Supplier.ID = Invoice.SupplierID
```

Then, if you do not want to display the field `CompanyName`, you can always hide that column in the datasheet form.
I usually hide the `ID` from reports as I only use them for identifying records internally to the database and make foreign relationships, the `ID` of each table is never shown to my users.

If your form is wired differently, then please amend your question with more information and a screenshot so we can answer you more accurately.

A small remarks regarding the code you provided:
you should be careful constructing your filter like you do: if the user types a `"`, your filter query will break. You should escape the user's input and sanitize it a bit.
At least do a `mQuery1 = Replace(Text22, """", "")`.
Similarly, if the user starts/ends his filter with a `*`, the query will probably won't work.